# How to proper escape quotes in SwayWM binding

Tags: screenshot, sway

I have a command to take screenshots of a selected window in SwayWM as follows:

```bash
grim -g "$(swaymsg -t get_tree | jq -r '.. | (.nodes? // empty)[] | select(.pid and .visible) | .rect | "\(.x),\(.y) \(.width)x\(.height)"' | slurp -o)"
```

It works perfectly on terminal, but when I add the command to a key binding:

```
bindsym Ctrl+Print exec grim -g "$(swaymsg -t get_tree | jq -r '.. | (.nodes? // empty)[] | select(.pid and .visible) | .rect | "\(.x),\(.y) \(.width)x\(.height)"' | slurp -o)"
```

It fails (when triggered) with the following error:

```
sh: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Looks like quote-escaping issue to me, but I can't make it work.
How can I propper escape the quotes and make the command work as expected?